# Can a spell cast inside a globe of invulnerability be counterspelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

If a spell caster is inside a [globe of invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability) and they try casting a spell, can somebody outside of the globe use [counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) to block their attempt to cast that spell? I had though it would not be possible, but the globe of invulnerability only protects creatures and object while counterspell is arguably targeting the spell itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, it can't

Counterspell "interrupt[s] a creature" - if that creature is within a Globe of Invulnerability then Counterspell "has no effect on them."

Comment: Yeah. My brain turned off for a minute there. Upcasting has no effect on the Globe, and counterspell is below the 5th level cutoff.

Answer (score 10):

### Nothing inside the globe can be affected by Counterspell even if you cast it at higher levels

Although your exact question has not been answered on Sage Advice, I believe the answer concerning how Dispel Magic applies to the Globe, [applies just as well](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/01/22/dispel-magic-vs-globe-of-invulnerability/):

> dispel magic could affect the barrier created by globe of invulnerability, but not anything inside the barrier

which aligns with the description of the Globe:

> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can’t affect creatures or objects within it, even if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot

So you're better off trying to use Dispel Magic to get rid of the Globe first.

Comment: What does "unless you go over 5th level" mean?

Comment: @kviiri that was sloppy wording. fixed

Comment: Just a heads up: you don't need to put a full line (***) between your link sources and the body text. The links will not appear in the text regardless and all it does is make a weird line at the very bottom of your answer that serves no purpose.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Roger that.